# Any future update planned for Magento1 to be combat upcoming GDPR changes?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1, magento-upgrade, gdpr

Does anybody know if Magento1 will release an update this month to be compatible with the `GDPR` changes due to be in place before the 25th of May 2018?

Just wondered if `Magento ver. 1.9.3.9` was planned to be released in time and would include changes to the admin area settings to allow stores to update policies/framework etc for `GDPR`.

Answer (score 0):

The GDPR is giving me headaches in regards to implementation and keeping up with upgrades after 25th of May.

For Magento 1 ZERO-1 has made an extension to cover the basics:
https://marketplace.magento.com/zero1-zero1-gdpr.html

This seems to be the only extension at the moment out there which tries to follow the GDPR law.

If anyone else has more info or plugins it's more than welcome.

Cheers,

Steve